# Using $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR) in User Header Search Path

Tags: iphone, ios, build, xcode4, header-files

When I use `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` in `User Header Search Path` (as recommended in [this](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/) tutorial about static libraries) XCode 4 resolves it like this:

[image]

This is a problem while I work with the simulator, because the build files are stored in `Debug-iphonesimulator` instead of `Debug-iphoneos`, and XCode fails to find headers.

My current workaround is build first for *iOS Device*, and then work with the Simulator. This is a bit tedious and error-prone. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The build products directory should be used for output by Xcode, and it is perfectly reasonable for these directories to be nonexistent at the time you begin to build. It is not advisable to have dependencies like user headers in these directories.

My recommendation would be to move the dependent headers out of the directory you're talking about.

Comment: Then how do you recommend working with static library header files of projects in the same workspace?

Comment: Isn't this fine as long as you add the other project's target as a direct dependency?

Comment: For _headers_ I would leave them as-is in their project and reference them directly from there - this will remove the requirement that you build a dependent library before you can compile anything in the client application that may use it. If you wanted you could split out those headers which are "public" v. the ones that are "private" into their own directories, and your application would only search for headers in the public folder.

Comment: For _library binaries_, I see where you're going to have a problem. It is possible to add a "Build Setting Condition" using the gear popup in the lower left corner of the build Target Info window. From there you can specify what the value should be depending on the target (Simulator, Device, etc.) and can use that to tell the linker where to look for the appropriate library binary. Note this will be an issue for linking the application, not compiling it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by doing the following. Instead of setting the User Header Search Paths to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` *recursive*, I set it explicitly to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/usr/local/include` *non-recursive*.

Comment: What exactly does this do? When I use this it won't find any of the other library stuff. But if I just use the `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}` then I run into problems using a file internally and externally.